# Kendo grid resizable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid in my project and a function like below:

```
function changeGrid(){
   $("#grid").empty().kendoGrid;

   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
       dataSource: DataSource,
       resizable: true,
       ...
    });
    ....
 }
```

The grid shown and everything is fine. But when i call the function `changeGrid()`, I will get error like this: `Unable to get value of the property 'removeClass': object is null or undefined`.

- the error is caused by the `resizable:true`, after i remove it, no error when  i call the function `changeGrid()`.

But I really need to have resizable in my grid. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
function changeGrid(){
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").destroy();
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: DataSource,
        resizable: true,
        ...
    });
    ....
}
```